# jwt-decode not working properly in React app

Tags: reactjs

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

 useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
        if(token){
            const user = jwt_decode(token)
        }
    }, [])
```

Error: export 'default' (imported as 'jwt_decode') was not found in 'jwt-decode' (possible exports: InvalidTokenError, jwtDecode)

I am trying to use the jsonwebtoken to decode the user information in React app and I took some references on the examples even I did `npm i jwt-decode --save` it still could not work properly as expected. May I ask what I am missing in order to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you checked your code against the documentation? https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#usage

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the export has been updated in the `jwt-decode` package. The default export is no more exists in the package.

The new export is `jwtDecode`. The error you have got also says about this.

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

 useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if(token){
            const user = jwtDecode(token);
        }
    }, [])
```

Please refer to their official [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#documentation) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Jwt-decode doesn't have a default export, and *jwt_decode* isn't a valid option.

This is the correct import to use the function that you need.

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const token = "eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token";
const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
```

If you'd like you can set an alias changing jwtDecode to jwt_decode, like this:

```
import {jwtDecode as jwt_decode} from 'jwt-decode';

const token = "eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token";
const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
```

However I'd recommend using the function the way it's served, it makes reading much easier

Answer (score 1):

According to the [README](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#readme) it should be:

```js
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
```

So the JavaScript error message is telling the truth (as it nearly always does)